# Как передать переменную из js в php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть несколько кнопок на странице и в зависимости от id кнопки будет выводится соответствующая форма. Условием вывода у меня является php, он сравнивает куки, если соответствуеn айди кнопки с куки, то выводит одну форму, если нет то другую. Вопрос как можно передать с помощью js айди кнопки в php, при этом php не в отдельном файле, а на этой же странице?

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE['user'] == айди кнопки):
?>
<p>Вывод одной формы</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Вывод другой формы</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: изменяете печеньки js скриптом через `document.cookie`, обновляете страницу  через `location.reload()`. Но это полнейшая дичь, никто не передаёт аргументы из js в php через печеньки. Для этого есть ajax, POST и GET методы http

Comment: самое простое что можно сделать - скрытое поле в форме с нужным значением, при отправке формы по нему можно будет ориентироваться